# Discord.py Giveaway Command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a giveaway command using discord.py. My code works, but I'm looking for a way to add a number of winners, for instance, if you put two as the amount of winners, it'll choose two people, if that makes sense.
Here's my current code:

```
time_regex = re.compile(r"(?:(\d{1,5})(h|s|m|d))+?")
time_dict = {"h": 3600, "s": 1, "m": 60, "d": 86400}

def convert(argument):
    args = argument.lower()
    matches = re.findall(time_regex, args)
    time = 0
    for key, value in matches:
        try:
            time += time_dict[value] * float(key)
        except KeyError:
            raise commands.BadArgument(
                f"{value} is an invalid time key! h|m|s|d are valid arguments"
            )
        except ValueError:
            raise commands.BadArgument(f"{key} is not a number!")
    return round(time)

@client.command()
@commands.has_role(': ̗̀➛ Giveaway Hosts')
async def start(ctx, timing, *, prize):
  await ctx.send('Okay, making a giveaway!', delete_after=3)
  gwembed = discord.Embed(
    title=" __**Giveaway**__ ",
    description=f'Prize: {prize}',
  )
  time = convert(timing)
  gwembed.set_footer(text=f"This giveaway ends {time} seconds from this message.")
  gwembed = await ctx.send(embed=gwembed)
  await gwembed.add_reaction("")
  await asyncio.sleep(time)
  message = await ctx.fetch_message(gwembed.id)
  users = await message.reactions[0].users().flatten()
  users.pop(users.index(ctx.guild.me))
  if len(users) == 0:
    await ctx.send("No winner was decided.")
    return
  winner = random.choice(users)
  await ctx.send(f"**Congrats {winner.mention}!**")
```

How do I add the winners as an option?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
time_regex = re.compile(r"(?:(\d{1,5})(h|s|m|d))+?")
time_dict = {"h": 3600, "s": 1, "m": 60, "d": 86400}

def convert(argument):
    args = argument.lower()
    matches = re.findall(time_regex, args)
    time = 0
    for key, value in matches:
        try:
            time += time_dict[value] * float(key)
        except KeyError:
            raise commands.BadArgument(
                f"{value} is an invalid time key! h|m|s|d are valid arguments"
            )
        except ValueError:
            raise commands.BadArgument(f"{key} is not a number!")
    return round(time)

@client.command()
@commands.has_role(': ̗̀➛ Giveaway Hosts')
async def start(ctx, timing, winners: int, *, prize):
  await ctx.send('Okay, making a giveaway!', delete_after=3)
  gwembed = discord.Embed(
    title=" __**Giveaway**__ ",
    description=f'Prize: {prize}',
    color=0xb4e0fc
  )
  time = convert(timing)
  gwembed.set_footer(text=f"This giveaway ends {time} seconds from this message.")
  gwembed = await ctx.send(embed=gwembed)
  await gwembed.add_reaction("")
  await asyncio.sleep(time)
  message = await ctx.fetch_message(gwembed.id)
  users = await message.reactions[0].users().flatten()
  users.pop(users.index(ctx.guild.me))
  if len(users) == 0:
    await ctx.send("No winner was decided.")
    return
  for i in range(winners):
    winner = random.choice(users)
    await ctx.send(f"**Congrats to: {winner}!**")
```

In this part, the part that chooses multiple winners:

```
  for i in range(winners):
    winner = random.choice(users)
    await ctx.send(f"**Congrats to: {winner.mention}!**")
```

For the amount of winners that you choose, it will choose a random winner and mention them. It mentions one person per message, so it might cause spam if you choose a lot of winners. Feel free to suggest edits.